# Tracking position of points after piecewiseAffineTransformation

Tags: image-processing, matplotlib, computer-vision, transform, scikit-image

I was following [this example](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_piecewise_affine.html) on Skimage website.The code does piece-wise affine transformation to the original image, and the resulting image looks like the image below.

[image: image resulted from the website example]

I tried to track how some specific points on the image move before and after the transformation by accessing the transform matrix index. Check my codes [here](https://gist.github.com/Po-Hsuan-Huang/7e2ad4c1d6b6ae8d64aedc2776183128)

I defined `find_map_index()` to find the index of the points in the transformation matrix

I also defined `find_linspace_index()` to put the specified points on the nearest grid points.

I was able to generate a image that looks like what I want as shown below. Blue points are the original and green stars are the resulting positions.
[image: image resulted from my code in gist]

My question is why do I have to use `tform.inverse`

```
out = warp(image, tform.inverse, output_shape=(rows + 100, cols))
```

instead of `tform` ?

```
out = warp(image, tform, output_shape=(rows + 100, cols))
```

Besides, how can I have an unclipped image without resizing it to fit into the size of the original image, which was the case in the website example ? The transformation seems to map points outside the original size on the image boundaries.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first part of the question - you need to use the inverse transform because the original transform is a forward mapping from the input image to the output image.

In creating the warped image you are in the space of the output image and for each pixel in your output image you want to find the corresponding location in the input image and you use the inverse transform to find this. See [skimage documentation for warp](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html?highlight=warp#skimage.transform.warp)

This approach ensures that you have a value for each pixel in your output image.

===========================

For the second part of your question that refers to clipping, as the documentation referred to above shows you have a number of options when the point in the output image results from outside the image extents of the input image. This is elaborated below with the corresponding definitions from numpy.pad

- constant - Pads with a constant value
- edge - Pads with the edge values of array
- symmetric - Pads with the reflection of the vector mirrored along the edge of the array
- reflect - Pads with the reflection of the vector mirrored on the first and last values of the vector along each axis
- wrap - Pads with the wrap of the vector along the axis. The first values are used to pad the end and the end values are used to pad the beginning

However, because the particular example you are referring to is a piece-wise affine transformation, it could also be constructed such that the region around the borders of the two images are fixed - i.e. the transform in this region is the identity matrix, so the points in this region are not warped. However, I'm not sure if that was the case in the example.

Comment: "you need to use the inverse transform because the original transform if a forward mapping from the input image to the output image." should be  "you need to use the inverse transform because the original transform **is** a forward mapping from the input image to the output image." Just spelling error. Thanks, this solved my problem. I padded the top and bottom of the image and did the transform.

Comment: @Kershaw - Thanks, amended in answer